# JSF 2.1 conditional field validation

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces

I have the following JSF 2.1 page

```html
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{userBean.newUser}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="new User" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="existing User" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
<br />
<h:inputText value="#{userBean.customerId}" id="customerId" />
<h:message for="customerid" />
<br />
<h:inputText value="#{userBean.firstName}" id="firstName" />
<h:message for="fisrtName" />
<br />
<h:inputText value="#{userBean.lastName}" id="lastName" />
<h:message for="lastName" />
<br />
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{userBean.login}" />
```

and this is my bean:

```
public class UserBean {

    private String customerId;
    private String newUser= "0";
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // Getters and seeters ommited.
}
```

I need to validate this form in the following way:

If the "new User" radio button selected, all form inputs should be validated. If "existing User" is selected I need to validate only the Customer Id.

I tried Hibernate Validation and I also tried a custom validator by implementing `javax.faces.validator.Validator` interface.

Can I achieve such functionality somehow?

Comment: what was the problem with the custom validator..? Why are you storing the flag for the new user in a string?

Comment: How can I set custom Validator conditionally? and what is the problem to store it as String?

Comment: well, I'd use a boolean or find out via the id of the user... anyway.. Can't you check in your validator if your user is already stored in the db, i.e. has an id and if not - validate all fields, if yes - validate only the customer id field

Comment: You can check conditions (reading parent component properties) and only if passed run validation logic. This logic throws ValidationException if validation fails.

Comment: @peshkira, I need to check it using radio buttons only :(

Comment: In validator methou you got args `FacesContext context, UIComponent component` Get component parent and search radio button components. Alternatively you can pass radio button ids as custom attributes to your validator and get them (e.g. from component) by id. But there is easier solution - look at my answer.

Comment: @zacheusz, How can I get UICompoment object value? It look like getSubmittedValue() is not available.

Comment: One more question. Maybe you only need check if field has value? Then look at BalusC solution.

Comment: @danny.lesnik let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1754/discussion-between-zacheusz-and-danny-lesnik)

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a [custom validator](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-validator-in-jsf-2-0/) which examines the parent UI component and performs validations only under certain conditions. It's quite complex. Maybe look at [ExtVal](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/validator/) and its `@SkipValidation` annotation?

```java
@SkipValidation("#{person.role eq 'admin'}")
@Required
@Equals("person.password")
@NotEquals("password")
private String oldPassword;
```